# Как настроить htaccess под файлы в MVC?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc, маршрутизация

есть проблема. Я сделал MVC на PHP, который распознает `/` в строке и делает соответствующие действия. Теперь встал вопрос в работе с файлами (подключение js и css). Я создал запроси в шаблон `files/js/js1.js`, которого нет и мне показывается ошибки о том, что не найден контроллер. Если разобрать URL, то это логично.

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы мой роутер на срабатывал на папку files вообще, чтобы я подключал даже не существующие файлы, но как файлы, а не попытка перейти на контроллер.

Спасибо.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Comment: А какой смысл подключать несуществующие файлы? Но если прям так хочется, то RewriteCond в помощь

Answer (score 0):

добавить условие `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/files/`